# Generate items in Ext.dataview.List from hasMany models the MVC way

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a `Blog` model with hasMany `Posts` (and many other fields). Now I want to list these posts in a `List`-view like that:

- [My post #1]
- [My post #2]
- [My post #3]

As far as the API described, I'm able to pass either a store or a data attribute to Ext.dataview.List. But I was not able to find out how to pass the hasMany records to the list so it will display an item for each of them.

Do I really have to create another store? Isn't it possible to configure my dataview to something like `store: 'Blog.posts'` or `data: 'Blog.posts'` or even `records: 'Blog.posts'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Adam Marshall said, this doesn't work as easy as I imagined.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the dataview.List to define the itemtpl to loop through the posts

```
itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for="**posts**" >',
        '<div>{TheBlogPost}</div>',
            '</tpl>'
)
```

Comment: But then I have one item only (listing my posts as inner HTML), right? What, if I want to have an item for each post?

Comment: Sorry yes you are correct, I looked at the dataview code but nothing stood out. Short of making a new store, or Overloading the Store to report more items than it has, i don't think what you are trying to do can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha autogenerates stores from associations if you know how to access them.
So you simply can switch out the list's store for the autogenerated "substore" when it has loaded.

This approach probably has some problems, e.g. when listpaging plugin is used, but it is quick.

Example:

**MODELS**

```
Ext.define('Conversation', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields: [

    ],
    associations:
        [
            {
                type: 'hasMany',
                model: "Message",
                name: "messages",
                associationKey: 'messages'
            }
        ]
}
});

Ext.define('Message' ,
{
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
        idProperty: 'id_message',
        fields: [
            { name: 'text', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'date', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'id_message', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'me', type: 'int'} // actually boolean
        ]
    }
}
    );
```

**JSON**

```
 [
{
    "messages": [

    {"id_message": 11761, "date": 1378033041, "me": 1, "text": "iiii"},
    {"id_message": 11762, "date": 1378044866, "me": 1, "text": "hallo"}
]}
]
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
        this.getList().getStore().load(
            {
                callback: function(records, operation, success) {

//IMPORTANT LINE HERE:
getList().setStore(Ext.getStore(me.getList().baseStore).getAt(0).messages());

                },
                scope: this
            }

        );
```

**LIST-VIEW**

```
                            {
                                flex: 1,
                                xtype: 'list',
                                itemId: 'ConversationList',
                                data: [],
                                store: 'ConversationStore',
                                baseStore: 'ConversationStore',
                                itemTpl:
                                        '                {[app.util.Helpers.DateFromTimestamp(values.date)]}<br><b>{name}</b>' +
                                        '           {[app.util.Helpers.fixResidualHtml(values.text)]} </div>' +
                            },
```